# Use static class as a variable

Tags: php

Say I have the following classes:

```
class App {
    public static $url;

    static function boot () {
        self::$url = new Url();
    }
}

class Url {
    function redirect ($url) {
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
}
```

How can I use this class like so:

```
App::boot();

$app = App;
$app->url->redirect('http://example.com');
```

???

Comment: Did you try this code? What happens? Or are we your interpreter?

Comment: It interprets `App` as a constant in my example and obviously doesn't work. How the hell is this off topic?

Comment: When asking a question you should **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why you want to have your class `App` as static?

Otherwise, you could do it like this:

```
class App {

    public $url;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->url = new Url();
    }

}

class Url {
    function redirect ($url) {
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
}

$app = new App();
$app->url->redirect('http://example.com');
```

If you want to keep it static:

```
class App {

    public static $url;

    public static function boot(){
        self::$url = new Url();
    }

}

class Url {
    function redirect ($url) {
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
}

App::boot();
App::$url->redirect('http://example.com');
```

Comment: I'm using it as a static so it is globally available. Also, I'm trying to pass it as a parameter in a blade template so I can utilize it's static objects within the templates themselves.

Comment: @kjdion84 You can try the 2nd way then. However, if I'm not mistaken, you can pass object instances to your blade templates.

Comment: I want to pass the entire `App` object into the template so I can use it as `$app`. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do this without having `use` declarations in the blade template itself. I'm using blade outside Laravel.

Comment: How are you passing your App object?

Comment: I figured it out. `$blade->make($view, $data)->with(['app' => '\\App\\Helpers\\App'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can access static properties using a variable (see code below), but I would recommend avoiding it.

```
class App {
    public static $url;
    public static function boot(){
        self::$url = new Url();
    }
}

class Url {
    function redirect ($url) {
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
}

$app = 'App';
$app::$url->redirect('http://example.com');
```